# How do I move a custom Word ribbon from one computer to another?

Tags: microsoft-word, ribbon

I have Word 2016 on one computer. Long ago, I installed a ribbon customization which added a tab named "Word 2003". Now, I'm switching to a new computer with Word 2019. I would like to install the same ribbon customization, but I can't figure out how.

According to the Word documentation, I should be able to go to Word Options / Customize Ribbon and export the ribbon settings to a file, which I can then import using Customize Ribbon on the new computer. However, the customized part of the ribbon doesn't appear anywhere in the Customize Ribbon form, so I can't export it.

I feel that there is some undocumented voodoo here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Word 2003 tab is almost certainly from an Add-In template which you can find in your Word [Startup Folder](http://addbalance.com/word/startup.htm). Copy the template to your new computer's startup folder.

The method recommend by Rich is for customizations that you created using the Modify the Ribbon method. In my opinion, that built-in method should never be used for customizations to be shared.

Comment: That was it! Actually, it turned out to be the file Normal.dotm in the "User templates" folder, not the Startup folder. I copied that file to the equivalent folder on the new computer, and everything works great.

Comment: That is almost certainly not a fully functional normal template. I still recommend putting it in the Word Startup folder on your new computer and letting Word create a new normal template. You will still have access to the Ribbon tab. You should rename it something like Word2003MenusTab.dotm.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Import/Export menu button on the Customize Ribbon dialog.

[image]

When you export, it doesn't include your custom tab? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Thank you, Rich, but that is not working. The custom tab "Word 2003" doesn't appear anywhere on the Main Tabs list. In other words, I somehow have a ribbon active in Word which Customize Ribbon doesn't acknowledge.

Comment: Where it says Main Tabs, pull down that menu and choose All Tabs. Does it show then?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.