# Copy complete custom ribbon tab in MS Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have added a custom tab in the MS Outlook (Office 365 ProPlus, version 1902) ribbon that shows in the main view.

I used (I have Outlook in Spanish, so I will translate the operations, with some possible minor errors):

1. *File* -> *Options* -> *Customize the ribbon* -> *New tab*.
2. Then I have *Right click* -> *Rename* the new tab.
3. Within the tab I have added 2 *New group*s. I renamed them.
4. Within each group I have added several commands from the left list, including some macros I have created.
5. I have assigned icons to each command in the ribbon.

Now when I open an email, I have a different ribbon in the view for a single email.
I want to have the same tab in this ribbon as in the main view.
I can recreate it following all the same steps, but that is quite cumbersome.

**Is there a way to copy that specific tab, from one view to the other? Perhaps "exporting" and "importing"...**

There is a button for Import/Export in the customization window.
And I have found [a related post](https://superuser.com/questions/1610109/how-do-i-move-a-custom-word-ribbon-from-one-computer-to-another) that describes how to use that to transfer a custom ribbon in Word, *from one **computer** to another*.
I do not know:

1. If that applies for transferring a single custom tab, *from one **view** to another* within the same application.
2. Otherwise, if it is possible to export the ribbon, and with some minor hand editing the exported file, applying it for my purpose.

Comment: According to my experience, there may be no option that could meet it, exporting and importing the settings just could backup and restore the whole settings and we couldn't change it to work for a specific group.